# ListView задать Tag

Tags: android, listview

Добрый вечер. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Нужно задать каждому Item в ListView свой Tag или ID, выбор пал на Tag потому, что он принимает String. У меня есть массив со String данными, нужными для присвоения каждому Item. Проблема в том, что когда я разбираю массив и в нем же присваиваю Tag, то по нажатию получаю только последний элемент. Хотя я уверен, что делаю все неправильно. Прошу помощи и заранее благодарю. [Код на Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Hxa3xasy) код:

```
        // MyHardArray - массив со значениями для списка, просто имена людей
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyHardArray);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Обработчик нажатия
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
                // Здесь имена людей которые будут отображены по нажатию
                String MyTextOnNewActivity = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();

                // пример массива с нужными данными в Tag
                // Разбираем его и присваиваем тэг
                String[] MyTagArray = new String[]{ "VasHello","TesWorld", "MekLeon", "SecMih" };
                for(String sT:MyTagArray){
                    view.setTag(sT);
                }
                            // Отправляем данные в другой Activity - Имена
                intent.putExtra(MY_TEXT_ON_NEW_ACTIVITY, MyTextOnNewActivity);
                            // Вот тут отправляется Тэг но только последний, мне нужно для каждого элемента свой
                intent.putExtra(MY_TAG_ON_NEW_ACTIVITY, view.getTag().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: @KRUZER, объясните, какого эффекта хотите добиться!  
Что это за массив temp? Ошибка, полагаю, в том, что вы пробегаете по этому массиву и присваиваете тэг для view элементами массива по очереди, и, естественно, только последний тэг присваивается!

Comment: @KRUZER, устанавливать tag надо в getView адаптера. Т.е. вам надо для начала реализовать свой адаптер. А в onClickListener уже поздно что-то присваивать...

Comment: Добиться эффекта разный тэг каждому Item. Есть сайт, возвращает ID => Имя. Я получаю Имя и вывожу их в Лист (успешно). Теперь хочу, чтобы по клику на имя внутри выводилось имя и ID, вот и все. Ошибка в том, что выводит один и тот же ID везде, в каждом имени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал модель с двумя полями: имя и id

```
class someData{
 String name;
 string id;
}
```

1. Получаем имена, создаем ArrayList<someData> array;
2. Пишем имена и id в этот массив!
3. Создаем адаптер и даем ему этот массив
4. По нажатию на пункт, someData data = adapter.getItem();
5. Отправляем в другую активити:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra(MY_TEXT_ON_NEW_ACTIVITY, data.name);                intent.putExtra(MY_TAG_ON_NEW_ACTIVITY, data.id);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, но уже решил проблему подобным способом. Всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(String sT:MyTagArray){
    view.setTag(sT);
}
```

Тут вы выставляете в тег по очереди каждую строчку из массива, но остается, естественно, последнее значение. Более простой пример того, что вы делаете:

```
int[] MyTagArray = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int view;
for(int i : MyTagArray){
    view = i;
}
```

Какое значение в итоге будет в i?  
Правильно, значение последнего элемента массива (9).  
Так же и в вашем коде в Tag оказывается всегда последний элемент массива.  
Вообще то, как вы это пытаетесь сделать - дичайший быдлокод, но если его попробовать сделать рабочим, то получится что-то типа:

```
String[] MyTagArray = new String[]{ "VasHello","TesWorld", "MekLeon", "SecMih" };
view.setTag(MyTagArray[position]
```

Comment: Создал Адаптер, передал данные из массива, установил теги и все такое. Выводит ListView отлично. Но вот теперь не передает данные при клике, может, подскажете, как их получить? Заранее благодарю! Код http://pastebin.com/HBwUPtsf

Comment: @KRUZER, проверьте, где у вас сейчас метод обработки нажатий сделан, и проверьте, как он конфликтует с созданным адаптером.